# ERROR Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: mysql, node.js, jwt

i am trying to do an authentitication using mysql and nodejs, and in the terminal returns an Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the cli
ent.  how  can i solve it?

`````
res.json({
     text:'protected'
});
});
app.post('/api/add',(req,res)=>{
    const sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET ? ';
    const userOBJ ={
        users:req.body.name,
        fullname:req.body.fullname,
        email:req.body.email,
        telephone:req.body.telephone,
        password:req.body.password

    };
    connection.query(sql,userOBJ,err=>{
        if(err)throw err;
    
        res.send('added customer');
    })
    jwt.sign({user:userOBJ},'users',(err,token)=>{
        res.json({
            token
        })
    }
    )
   
    
});
function verifyToken(req,res,next){
    const bearerHeader =req.headers ['authorization']
    if(typeof bearerHeader !=='undefined'){
   const bearerToken= bearerHeader.split(' ')[1] 
   req.token =bearerToken
   next()
    }else{
        res.sendStatus(403)
    }
}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

In the `'/api/add'` route, you're calling both `res.send()` and `res.json()` on the same request.  That will cause the error you see about headers already sent.
Pick one or the other as you can only send one response for each http request.

In addition, you have asynchronous issues and a lack of error handler handling on the database call.  You need to nest the second block of code inside the database callback so they are sequenced appropriately and you need to actually send an error response if you get an error from your database.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using the two response in a api res.send() & res.json(), please send only one response for a request.